# Liferay : ServiceBuilder finder is avialable in LocalServiceUtil , until i restrated the Machine

Tags: liferay

In the `service.xml`file added the following finder Method

```xml
<finder name=”City” return-type=”Collection”>
    <finder-column name=”city”></finder-column>
</finder>
```

**Ran the ant target “ant build-service”**

In the `SampleUtil.java`, Copied the finder method from this class and paste it inside the `SampleLocalServiceImpl`class and modify the method definition

```java
public static java.util.List<com.sample.model.Sample> findByCity(
    java.lang.String city) throws com.liferay.portal.SystemException {

    return SampleUtil.findByCity(city);
}
```

**Ran the target “ant build-service” again.**

But the finder is avialable in `SampleLocalServiceUtil`, until i restrated the Machine .

Please let me know , why is that so ?? Or am i missing something .

Thanks

```java
List<Sample> customerList = SampleLocalServiceUtil.findByCity(“cityname”);
```

Comment: Is that a `static` method that you add to `SampleLocalServiceImpl` or a typo?

Answer (score 0):

To use the "finder" I would use the instance of the persistence class available to you in the `LocalService`.

To extend your example,

Instead of `SampleUtil.findByCity(city)`, do `samplePersistence.findByCity(city)`.

`samplePersistence` will already be created for you by the base implementation of `SampleLocalServiceImpl.java`.